# why duplicate layer and blend normal display different image than original?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As I assume, it should make no visual difference if duplicate a layer and then show both layer using normal?

forgot to mention, both layers have opacity setting 100%

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there will be a difference if the image has translucent pixels. Pixel build-up will cause some pixels to appear darker.

Stack an 80% opaque pixel on top of another 80% opaque pixel and things will look 100% opaque.